# What difference does it make, HDFS filesystem being stored in user space instead of kernel space?

Tags: hadoop, filesystems, hdfs

As I understand HDFS is written in java.

HDFS is nothing but a file system that .It resides within the user space unlike traditional file systems like FAT, NTFS, ext2, etc that reside on the kernel space.

Could somebody please clarify ?

Comment: it's just, that you do not want to run java in kernel-space.

Answer (score 2):

What your understanding is correct. Unlike `FAT,XFS,EXT` filesystems. HFDS requires an underlying filesystem to work and it is running userspace not in kernel.